Correspondence of Sylow p-Subgroups between Group $G$ and Quotient Group $G/Q$
Let $G$ be a finite group, $p$ a prime factor of $|G|$, $Q$ a $p$-subgroup of $G$, and $Q$ a normal subgroup of $G$. Let $\pi: G \to G/Q$ be the quotient homomorphism. Prove that $\pi$ induces a one-to-one correspondence between the Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ and the Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G/Q$.
Difficulties Encountered

If I have a Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ of $G$, by the Correspondence Theorem, $\pi(P)$ is also a subgroup of $G/Q$, but how can I determine that $\pi(P)$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G/Q$?

I can only prove that the conjugacy classes of Sylow $p$-subgroups in $G$ correspond to subgroups in $G/Q$ that are also conjugate in $G/Q$,
$$
\pi(gPg^{-1}) = \pi(g)\pi(P)\pi(g^{-1})
$$
but I cannot prove a one-to-one correspondence.



Check the orders.

I want to give a general explanation of what is happening. It is quite long but every step is simple and with not much coputations. I will only use the facts that $(i)$ $p$-Sylows are maximal $p$-subgroups, and $(ii)$ they are all conjugates.
We know that there is an increasing correspondence
\begin{align*}
\{ \textrm{subgroups of } G \textrm{ that contains } Q \} &\leftrightarrow \{ \textrm{subgroups of } G/Q \} \\
H &\rightarrow \pi(H) \\
\pi^{-1}(K) &\leftarrow K.
\end{align*}
Note that those mapping are increasing, that is, if $H_1\subset H_2$ are subgroups of $G$ that contains $G$, then $\pi(H_1) \subset \pi(H_2)$.
The above correspondence can be specified into the $p$-groups. We have the correspondence
\begin{align*}
\{ p\textrm{-subgroups of } G \textrm{ that contains } Q \} &\leftrightarrow \{ p\textrm{-subgroups of } G/Q \} \\
H &\rightarrow \pi(H) \\
\pi^{-1}(K) &\leftarrow K,
\end{align*}
which is well defined, as the image of a $p$-group by a morphism is still a $p$-group. For the latter side, if $K$ is a subgroup of $G/Q$, then we have $\textrm{Card}(\pi^{-1}(K)) = \textrm{Card}(K) \cdot \textrm{Card}(Q)$. As $Q$ is a $p$-group, if $K$ is a $p$-subgroup of $G/Q$, then $\pi^{-1}(K)$ is a $p$-subgroup of $G$.
By $(i)$ a $p$-Sylow is no more than a maximal $p$-subgroup, thus I have the third correspondence
\begin{align*}
\{ p\textrm{-Sylow of } G \textrm{ that contains } Q \} &\leftrightarrow \{ p\textrm{-Sylow of } G/Q \} \\
H &\rightarrow \pi(H) \\
\pi^{-1}(K) &\leftarrow K.
\end{align*}
Now let $P$ be a general $p$-Sylow of $G$. Then $\pi(P)$ is a $p$-subgroup of $G/Q$. If it were a $p$-Sylow, by the correspondence there would be a $p$-Sylow $P'$ of $G$ that contains $Q$ such that $\pi(P) = \pi(P')$. We would then have $P' = \pi^{-1}(\pi(P')) = \pi^{-1}(\pi(P)) \subset P$, with equality if and only if $P$ contains $Q$ ! But it needs to be an equality, as every $p$-Sylow of $G$ have the same cardinality. Thus if $\pi(P)$ is a $p$-Sylow, then $P$ is a $p$-Sylow of $G$ that contains $Q$. We thus have proved ; 
"If $P$ is a $p$-group of $G$, then $\pi(P)$ is a $p$-Sylow of $G/Q$ if and only if $P$ is a $p$-Sylow of $G$ that contains $Q$." 
It is a statement a bit different than the one given by the correspondence.
But now is the funny thing ; As $Q$ does have a $p$-Sylow, by the correspondence there is a $p$-Sylow $P$ of $G$ that contains $Q$. By $(ii)$ if $P'$ is an other $p$-Sylow of $G$, there exist some $a\in G$ such that $P' = aPa^{-1}$. As $Q$ is normal, we have that $aQa^{-1}=Q$, and because $Q\subset P$, we have $Q=aQa^{-1} \subset aPa^{-1} = P'$. Thus $Q$ is contained in every $p$-Sylow of $G$ ! Thus, the third correspondence is actually the correspondence you were searching for, that is
\begin{align*}
\{ p\textrm{-Sylow of } G\} &\leftrightarrow \{ p\textrm{-Sylow of } G/Q \} \\
H &\rightarrow \pi(H) \\
\pi^{-1}(K) &\leftarrow K.
\end{align*}
Hope that it was useful.

It is enough to prove the following proposition. After that you can apply Sylow Theory in $G/N$ which gives you the conjugation part.

Proposition If $N \unlhd G$, $P \in Syl_p(G)$, then $PN/N \in Syl_p(G/N)$.  Conversely, every Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G/N$ is of the form $PN/N$ for some $P \in Syl_p(G)$.

Proof Let $P \in Syl_p(G)$. Then $PN/N \cong P/(P \cap N)$. Hence $PN/N$ as an isomorphic quotient of $P$, is a $p$-subgroup of $G/N$. Further, $|G/N:PN/N|=|G:PN|$, which divides $|G:P|$. So $|G/N:PN/N|$ is not divisible by $p$, whence $PN/N \in Syl_p(G/N)$.
Conversely, assume that $Q/N \in Syl_p(G/N)$. Take a $P \in Syl_p(G)$ and consider the $p$-subgroup $PN/N$ of $G/N$. It follows that $PN/N \subseteq (Q/N)^{\bar{g}}$ for some $\bar{g} \in G/N$ (this follows from the general and well-known fact that in an arbitrary finite group a $p$-subgroup is always contained in some Sylow $p$-subgroup, and that Sylow Theory holds in any finite group, in particular $G/N$). It follows that $P \subseteq PN \subseteq Q^g$. Since $P$ is Sylow in $G$, $|Q^g:PN|$ is not divisible by $p$. On the other hand, $|Q^g:PN|$ divides $|Q^g:N|$, which is a power of $p$ (observe $|Q:N|=|Q^g:N|$). This yields that $|Q^g:PN|=1$, that is $Q^gN=P$, or equivalently, $Q=P^{g^{-1}}N$, and the conjugate of $P$, $P^{g^{-1}} \in Syl_p(G)$. $\square$
